# Is it possible to install Fedora from a native installation?

Tags: linux, fedora, installer

The only way I know to install Fedora is to create a Live-Installation from an iso file on some writable device, boot from that device and run the actual installation.

Problem is: when I want to do additional stuff before installing (e.g. making a full backup from the device I want to install on) I need free space on the device containing the live system. Or sometimes I want to install tools like `gparted`, `ddrescue` etc., setup Wifi or something else which gets lost on reboot.

My question is: isn't it somehow possible to install Fedora from a totally native Fedora installation? I'd like something like

```
dnf install fedora-installer
fedora-installer /dev/usb0    # will install Fedora, and NOT create a live-installation
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not, exactly. The installer isn't designed for this case. *However*, for the case you've described, where you want to do additional stuff before the install, the LiveCD should be perfect. Boot into that, install the tools you need *into the live image*, and use them before launching the installer itself.